# RequireJS as module loader for UserScripts hosted on github

Tags: coffeescript, userscripts, requirejs

I'm writing a sample UserScript, hosted as a gist, with RequireJS as module loader.

Here it is: https://gist.github.com/1809547/4dd8eed18810525f1ae41f685f739870748c94f2

The gist is as followed:

- `hola.user.js` is the installable userscript — which will greet you
- `index.js` is the main controller file
- other files are modules of 'hola' (`greetings` and `speech`)

Everything works great: if you [install the hola userscript](https://gist.github.com/1809547/4dd8eed18810525f1ae41f685f739870748c94f2/hola.user.js), it should greet you in the console with a nice:

> hi!

--

But I get into troubles [when trying to introduce CoffeeScript support](https://gist.github.com/1809547/c47128d6f2725bf340a1007ea20c628a4999eb0e), for example on `index.coffee`

I then got a cross-origin issue:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://raw.github.com/gist/1809547/index.coffee. Origin http://example.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any idea to workaround this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your reference to the cs plugin has the wrong url.

Line #35 of [your code](https://gist.github.com/1809547/c47128d6f2725bf340a1007ea20c628a4999eb0e) references

```
cs: 'https://raw.github.com/jrburke/require-cs/master/cs'
```

but the correct link has a .js extension-- should be:

```
cs: 'https://raw.github.com/jrburke/require-cs/master/cs.js'
```

Comment: no, this is good: the https://raw.github.com/jrburke/require-cs/master/cs.js ressource is correctly loaded into the document with this syntax.